# Magento Can't Make Product Changes Unless Manually Change Data And Save

Tags: admin, cache, product-attribute, reindex

I can only update products when I manually go into the product page, change something and then save it. It won't update through magmi or bulk import or sql query.

I accidently changed the product name to the image url. I have changed it back through an upload and on the front-end it shows the product name but on the admin page it still shows the product url as the 'name' so it's hard to search for items.

The actual database shows 'name' (attribute_id = 71) as the correct name. So where is the back-end taking the data from?

If I manually go into a product and add 'test' to the end of 'name' and click save, the back-end (admin) will update, but I can't do this manually for every product.

Something seems to be happening when you click save that you cannot do via an upload?

And I have re-indexed all of it many times, through SSH aswell.
Cleared cache, deleted var/cache folder.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What version of Magento

Comment: and you are bulk updating the catalog product EAV tables and not Flat tables correct?

Comment: its version 1.8.1

Comment: I was checking SQL table catalog_product_entity_varchar for product names

Answer (score 1):

I have previously had the issue where the value was only updated on a store level and so in the admin section you had to go into the product and select a store from the drop down on the left hand side.

If the value is set in the database make sure that the store_id is 0, if it is not then the value might only be set on a front end store level and not the admin store.

Comment: Hi, yes it seemed to only be set on front end and not the admin. I've resolved it now but was a lot of troubleshooting!

Comment: @ESavage what was the issue in the end?

Comment: The database stores product name three times in the same table, one of which must be the admin view, so updated that seperately